# Skaffold remote deployment does not push to container registry

Tags: kubernetes, google-container-registry, skaffold

In the [skaffold documentation](https://skaffold.dev/docs/environment/local-cluster/) it says it will auto-detect a local cluster based upon the kubernetes context and, if it is not a local-cluster, it will push to a container repo.

I am running skaffold on a Mac, I do not see that behavior.  When I run it with `skaffold run` on minikube, it does what I expect. But when I change the context to my remote cluster, it does not push the image to the remote container registry.  I'm somewhat new to skaffold so I would love any ideas on how to debug this or anything that might cause this behavior.

Edit: adding my ~/.skaffold/config file

```yaml
global:
  local-cluster: true
  survey:
    last-prompted: "2021-01-18T14:06:13-05:00"
kubeContexts:
- kube-context: minikube
  local-cluster: true
```

Comment: Check your `skaffold.yaml` for having `build.local.push: false` or your `~/.skaffold/config` is marking your cluster (or all clusters) as `local-cluster` (https://skaffold.dev/docs/design/global-config/).  It would help if you included both files here.

Comment: @BriandeAlwis I think I see the problem. Thanks for pointing that out. I added my configuration above.  So I'm assuming that global: local-cluster: true is what I need to fix, right?  If so, please add that as an answer to this so I can give you credit. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `local-cluster: true` in your `~/.skaffold/config` instructs Skaffold to treat that cluster as a local-cluster.  When in the `global` section, Skaffold will treat *all* clusters as local.